# found this hidden file on our pc desktop

Tags: mac, email, desktop-computer

Mac OS X  2°âATTR;šÉÿâÜÀÜ‹%com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFromsg5)com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDatebplist00¡_\https://mail.ovh.net/roundcube/?_task=mail&_uid=685&_mbox=INBOX&_action=viewsource&_extwin=1 ibplist00¡3A½º!<ã…è This resource fork intentionally left blank ÿÿ

I am on a mac and I share the routeur with a pc?  Can anyone tell me what this file is doing?  Is it spying on my email?

thanks a million
Gran

Comment: Was that mess the name of the file or the contents of the file? If the contents, then what was the filename?

Answer (score 1):

Im not expert in Mac OS, but look like you accessed PC desctop folder from MAC, and Mac OS store own attributes which have no native place in windows filesystem.
Im usually see some strange Mac stuff on USB drives accessed from MAC OS.

Comment: thanks mmv  That file was on the desktop of our pc. I am on mac. Roundcube is an email service we use.  I thought it had something to do about accessing mac from the pc???